# Azure + Windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, azure, azure-storage

I am planning on a photo app, and want to know how I could upload/ download images from windows phone 7 to the blob storage as well as access the table storage. I don't mind placing the access key on the application, since the app is planned to be distributed internally only. 
Since the Azure API is not available can somebody tell me how I can do the same ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can:

- use [Azure BLOB API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd135733.aspx) directly (including key on the phone)
- Abstract Blob operations behind a server-side web service

I also recommend to check out article by Steve Marx on [accessing Azure Blob from Silverlight](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/uploading-windows-azure-blobs-from-silverlight-part-1-shared-access-signatures). It covers a wide range of topics including [Shared Access Signatures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee395415.aspx) and how to actually work with Azure Blob API.

Answer (score 3):

I would not place the Access key into any client device. You should think about creating a webservice which can handle the upload for you. That way your phone has not to know about the Azure API.

Answer (score 1):

Try to decouple your Phone 7 application from the backend implementation. Windows Phone 7 supports XNA and Silverlight applications so I guess you're going for the latter. That implies that you need to connect to a service anyway. I would suggest that you put all the backend and Azure specific logic behind a WCF service and call that from within your application.